# use htonl convert a int number, and memcpy to a char*, but nothing

Tags: memcpy, htonl

code like this:

```
int totalLen = 50;

int usTest = htons(totalLen);

char* strBuf = new char[totalLen ];

memcpy(strBuf,&usTest,sizeof(int));
```

after this,there is nothing in strBuf, why?

but if I put a big number, like `100000001`, it will be OK?

what's the problem?

Comment: What value is in the variable `len`?

Comment: the length of reqMsg!

Comment: memcpy(&strBuf + sizeof(int),reqMsg,len); shuld like this,even I remove this statement,it is still nothing in strBuf,so the problem is no on this statement.

Comment: i modify the code,try

Comment: Note that `htons()` returns an `uint16_t` (or equivalent), not an `int`, and as such, you should only `memcpy()` `sizeof(uint16_t)` bytes, not `sizeof(int)` bytes...