# converting uint32_t htonl to char[4] using memcpy does not give output

Tags: c++, memcpy, arrays, endianness, htonl

My question is kind of similar to the one in this link [use htonl convert a int number, and memcpy to a char*, but nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818704/use-htonl-convert-a-int-number-and-memcpy-to-a-char-but-nothing) , and there are some other similar questions, but the reason Im asking a new one is because I have not been able to find a solution. What I wanna do is prepend the length of the message as 4 bytes from htonl before sending the actual message (sendBuffer)

```
int packed_len = strlen(dataInChar);  //dataInChar is the serialized char array
char myByteArray[sizeof(int)];
uint32_t bigEndianValue = htonl(packed_len);  // convert the value to big-endian for cross-platform compatibility
memcpy(myByteArray, &bigEndianValue, sizeof(uint32_t));
std::cout<<"myByteArray length: "<<strlen(myByteArray)<<std::endl;  //output 0

char sendBuffer[1024]; //final buffer to send
memcpy(sendBuffer, &myByteArray, 4);
memcpy(sendBuffer+4, dataInChar, strlen(dataInChar));
std::cout<<"sendBuffer length: "<<strlen(sendBuffer)<<std::endl;  //output 0
```

I have not touched c++ in years so please forgive bear with me on any stupid stuff that im doing wrong here.

Comment: strlen() is for zero terminated strings, you're working with binary data, so you'll have to track the length yourself. It's somewhat unclear what you actually want to do though, and whether your `dataInChar` is also binary data, or a zero terminated string. `strlen(myByteArray)` is not needed, you just copied in `sizeof(uint32_t)` , so that's its size. (which would be 4).

Comment: You should be more consistent in your use of sizes.  You are using `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(uint32_t)`, and `4` for the size of `myByteArray`.  This is fine as long as all of these are the same.  However, if this is run on a system with non-32 bit integers, then the code will not behave correctly.

Comment: But how do I make sure that bigEndianValue is being copied to myByteArray? and that value needs to be prepended to sendBuffer before I can append dataInChar (serialized data) in sendbuffer.
Typically I wanna do 
memcpy(sendBuffer, &myByteArray, strlen(myByteArray);
memcpy(sendBuffer+strlen(myByteArray), dataInChar, strlen(dataInChar));
but I knowmyByteArray is 4 bytes that why I had hard-coded it there

Comment: @Dhruv You don't need to make sure. You used memcpy() to copy the value. As long as you pass valid data to memcpy(), it works, there's nothing to check for, and if you pass invalid data, you get undefined behavior, which you cannot check for. Your problem is the `cout` statement, where you use `strlen(myByteArray)`, where you can instead just use `4`, or `sizeof(int)`. The next problem is `strlen(sendBuffer)` , which should be `4 + strlen(dataInChar)`. Now, if `dataInChar` is also binary data, you naturally cannot use `strlen(dataInChar)`, but need to track its length by other means.